# Breadcrumb NavXT plugin - exclude 'home' page

Tags: plugins, breadcrumb

Does anyone know how to exclude the breadcrumb from appearing on the 'home' page only using this plugin? I have currently got it set up in the header template and so it is appearing on every page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Opne you header.php file and look for something like this:

```
<div class="breadcrumbs">
<?php
if(function_exists('bcn_display'))
{
    bcn_display();
}
?>
</div>
```

then before the call for `bcn_display();` make sure you are not on the home page so basicaly replace `bcn_display();` with:

```
if(!is_home() && !is_front_page()){bcn_display();}
```